# Create a new file that is not empty but contains some hard-coded content by default

Tags: xml, javafx

I am learning and doing a simple text/XML editor in JavaFX. I have file menu with "New" action that creates a new tab on my `TabPane`. Now I would like to extend it so that when the user creates a new tab (that will be eventually saved into a file), that tab is pre-filled with some minimal content.

For the sake of example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

</root>
```

What is the recommended way for achieving something like this?

For example, I can create a new file in a my project structure that contains the above text and then every time when I 'create' a new file I actually open it and presented it as if new. But then I will have to modify my "Saving" logic to save the tab as a new file, and not overwrite the existing one.
So that does not seem like a good approach.

My editor class has the following content:

```
public class Editor implements Content {
    public TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    public String filename = null;

    public TextArea getRoot() {
        return textArea;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        textArea.setText(text);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textArea.getText();
    }
}
```

and it Implements this simple interface:

```
public interface Content {
    public Node getRoot();
}
```

I am not sure if this code is enough, for you to propose an approach/good practice. If not, let me know and I will share the

Comment: I may be missing something, but why don't you just initialize the text area with the default text?

Comment: Yeah that works and it's better. But what other options are there? Or to put it in another way - is there a better way to it? or that's the best approach since it's also the simplest?

Comment: I would start with a fixed default string. Then once you have that working, you could progress to letting the user configure the text, by reading from a file as jewelsea suggests. You could even progress later to including a part of the ui that configures the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a hardcoded string, just do:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "<?xml versio...";
. . . 
Editor editor = new Editor();
editor.setText(DEFAULT_TEXT);
```

---

If you want to support configurable templates for the default text, you could place the template text in a resource text file (e.g. utf-8 encoded) and read it from that:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes("template.xml"), "utf-8");
```

Above uses a file, but from the file system, but you could also use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` to read it from your application class path.

---

As you get more skill, you might want to investigate replacing your TextArea based editor with a syntax highlighting editor such as [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) or an [HTML based syntax highlighting editor embedded in a WebView](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1463485) (but get your basic app working with just the TextArea first before investigating these other options).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the additional links. RichTextFX looks nice.